Kestrel not using default certificate from appsettings.json
I've been using the default certificate from appSettings.json in a bunch of ASP.NET Core applications without any issues.
"Kestrel": {
  "Certificates": {
    "Default": {
      "Subject": "localhost",
      "Store": "MY",
      "Location": "LocalMachine",
      "AllowInvalid": true
    }
  }
}

This should take a certificate with subject 'localhost' from Local Machine - Personal.
This works in my normal apps that use a Startup.cs and wire up the KestrelServerOptions to use the Kestrel section from appsettings.json
.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(config.GetSection("Kestrel"))
Now, in my latest app, I have two app hosts, one hosting a regular web API on one port, another one hosting a combination of coreWCF and REST API. My app instantiates the former using this code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services
    .Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(config.GetSection("Kestrel"))
    .AddControllers();
builder.WebHost.UseUrls(["https://+:8070"]);
var adminApp = builder.Build();
adminApp.MapControllers();
adminApp.Start();

That all works fine, but it takes the developer certificate (which has the same subject but is in the CurrentUser store and has a different expiration so I know it's not taking the right one).
Is there something I'm missing when using WebApplication.CreateBuilder() instead of your usual
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup(context => new Startup(config, Startup.GetLogger<Startup>(config)));
        };

I've done some more investigating, and the issue is even weirder. If I specify a non existing certificate, then starting the app host (adminApp.Start()) gets me an exception that the certificate with subject xy can't be found. If a specify an existing certificate, it is ignored and the developer certificate is served (and on a box without the .NET SDK, I'm getting the message that no developer certificate is found). So, somehow it seems to default to the developer certificate even when another certificate is found. I turned on logging to the max, but not seeing anything that would give me a clue.
When I end up configuring the ListenOptions manually, so instead of builder.WebHost.UseUrls(...), I'm doing (I omitted the reading of the values from appSettings.json for the CertificateLoader)
var cert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(certSubject, store.ToString(), location, allowInvalid);
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options => 
{
    options.ListenAnyIp(8070, listenOptions => listenOptions.UseHttps(cert);
});

it works as expected but that completely bypasses the certificate selection from appSettings.json and it's not as flexible. You can extend it parse the urls you want to listen to and then use options.Listen to get to the same result, but I'd really like to use the standard config file approach.

Do you mean if you are using above codes both WCF and api all use the VS dev certificate?  How you run these two application ? Directly using command or else?

The second app host (using WCF) is currently not encrypted (it's net.tcp, not http/soap). All my apps are CLI apps (you were probably thinking one was IIS the other cli or something.. but they're the same). I'll guess I'll just have to fetch the cert config from the IConfiguration and manually tell the app host to use the cert in question.

You mean it still use the Kestrel as the host server?

I don't understand the question. Do you mean how is the application started? Every application I have is a windows service, I'm using the generic service hosting mechanism (Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseWindowsService()....) to host my implementation of a BackgroundService which in itself then runs the app (and the app does what's described above). Did you catch my updates? it seems the config is not fully ignored, but depending on config, the dev cert is used instead of the cert specified.
